# How to use retrofit for this type of URL

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am using retrofit in kotlin to get list of issues from github reposetories. I want to use the search api (I have used api.github.com/repos but my usecase requires /search).
How can I implement the following format of the query?

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=something%20repo:torvalds/linux%20state:closed

how to use the colon based space seperated query?

my code is like this but I am obviously wrong

```
@GET("search/issues")
suspend fun getRepoIssues(
    @Header("Authentication") authToken: String,
    @Query("q") q: String
): Response<APIResponse>
```

i am getting 422 error